# insert an array in facebook messenger php

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, loops, messenger

I created a bot with php with the code below :

```
$answer = ["attachment"=>[
  "type"=>"template",
  "payload"=>[
    "template_type"=>"generic",
    "elements"=>[
      [
        "title"=>"TEST",
        "image_url"=>"http://www...",
        "subtitle"=>"sub TEST",
        "buttons"=>[
          [
            "type"=>"web_url",
            "url"=>"http://www...",
            "title"=>"Info"
          ] 
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]];
```

Everything works but I need to create a loop (while or foreach) for "elements" to display from an another array a list of different elements.

How I can add this loop inside this array $answer?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

foreach( $elements as $element )
{
    $answer['attachment']['payload']['elements'][] = $element;
}

?>
```